# Extending the Function interface in the presence of an import statement

Tags: typescript

I would like to extend `Function` and this compiles fine

```
interface Function {
    hello(): any
}
Function.prototype.hello = function() {
    console.log('hello world')
}

function noop() {}

noop.hello() //==> 'hello world' in the console
```

However, as soon as I try to add an import statement, say

```
import { sayHello } from './Anything'
```

where `Anything` only contains

```
export function sayHello() { console.log('hello')}
```

The compilation fails on `Function.protoype.hello` with the message `error TS2339: Property 'hello' does not exist on type 'Function'`

Why ?

[View in Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20Function%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09hello()%3A%20any%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Function.prototype.hello%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09console.log('hello%20world')%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%0A%09function%20noop()%20%7B%7D%0A%09%0A%09noop.hello()%0A%09%0A%09%2F%2Fimport%20%7B%20hello%20%7D%20from%20'whatever'%20%20%0A%09%2F*%0A%09%20*%20Adding%20the%20import%20statement%20(also)%20triggers%20the%20Error%3A%20%0A%09%20*%20Property%20'hello'%20does%20not%20exists%20on%20type%20%60Function%60%0A%09%20*%20Why%20%3F%0A%09%20*%2F)

Note: the compilation fails with tsc options set to either `--target es5 --module commonjs` or `--target es6`

Comment: Obviously you are trying to do something in the wrong way, changing a prototype in typescript or es6 sounds wrong. Why not just explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @gilamran. :-D. When I have "sounds" problems, I promise, I will contact you.

Comment: I was not joking, Instead of giving a "sayHello" example, say your real intentions and we will solve it for you. If you are just trying to understand something in TypeScript, explain what are you trying to understand. Anyways, your question is not related to TypeScript, it is probably related to es6 module import/export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great answer here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5944

In short when introducing `export` (or `import`) the whole file is considered to be in its own separate namespace: `Function` is now evaluated as a local interface and is no more referring to the global definition.

I also recommend reading the whole discussion there: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4166

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the compiler doesn't know you extended the basic function type. Try:

```
export interface Function {...}
```

Comment: Thanks but no, that does not fix it